# How to run filter on demand scala play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm developing a scala application with play frame work, i have created a filter that filters every request coming from outside server,but now i'm stuck on how can i run a filter on demand since two days,i have 80 APIs 30 of them needs to run a specific filter, how can i read the request route template while the requests like this

```
 GET /api/v1/:locale/:uuid core.controllers.MyClass.myAction1(locale: String)
 GET /api/v1/:locale/:uuid/MyRoute core.controllers.MyClass.myAction2(locale: String)
 GET /api/v1/:locale/:uuid/Foo core.controllers.MyClass.myAction3(locale: String)
 GET /api/v1/:locale/orders/:orderId core.controllers.MyClass.myAction4(locale: String)
```

well, those routes are placed in routes file, 
in filter i need to check weather if the route has **:uuid** variable or **:orderId** in order to run its specific filter, because both of their ids, i getting them as uuid so i couldn't expect the request, could i read the route template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to some routing information from the `RequestHeader#attrs`:

```
// in your filter
val handlerDef: Option[HandlerDef] = request.attrs.get(Router.Attrs.HandlerDef)
```

See [HandlerDef api](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.routing.HandlerDef)

Comment: i think this is the best solution, i can make many filters with make any attention to the url template

Comment: Well, why in the url variable display an regular expression like this 
/api/v1/$locale<[^/]+>/
could you please tell me what is going on here

Comment: The routing file is interpreted and interpreted before generating the router implementation. You can use regular expressions in the routing file: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRouting#Dynamic-parts-with-custom-regular-expressions

When using `/api/v1/:locale/` it will be rewritten to use a regular expression so it can be used directly by the framework

Comment: Is it unsafe to `.get` on this to take it out of the Option? When would `Router.Attrs.HandlerDef` not be present?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to choose 30 out of 80 actions to run some common logic, you could also consider using "action builders" to provide that logic.

When you use `Action { ... }` you get a vanilla action. You can also make your own `MyAction { ... }` that wraps a normal `Action` and runs custom logic. This is an `ActionBuilder`. If you use this approach you just need to update your 30 actions to use that custom action builder.

See: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActionsComposition#Custom-action-builders

Comment: i think action builder will be hard a bit

Comment: No problem, the `HandlerDef` is fine too. I actually wrote the code in Play Framework that stores the `HandlerDef` in a request attribute. :) The benefit of action builders is that things are a bit more typesafe and explicit - but sometimes filters are a better option.