# When would request.attrs.get in a Scala Play custom filter return None?

Tags: scala, filter, playframework, routes

In [an answer to "How to run filter on demand scala play framework"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47271180/8230810), the following code is suggested:

```scala
// in your filter
val handlerDef: Option[HandlerDef] = request.attrs.get(Router.Attrs.HandlerDef)
```

I'm not sure what's happening here - is it safe to `.get` on this val (to get it out of the Option)? In what scenarios would this code result in a `None` (ie, when would `Router.Attrs.HandlerDef` not be present)?

I'm working with Scala and PlayFramework 2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Route modifier tags](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Highlights26#Route-modifier-tags)

> Please be aware that the `HandlerDef` request attribute exists only when
>   using a router generated by Play from a `routes` file. This attribute is
>   not added when the routes are defined in code, for example using the
>   Scala SIRD or Java `RoutingDsl`. In this case
>   `request.attrs.get(HandlerDef)` will return `None` in Scala or `null` in
>   Java. Keep this in mind when creating filters.

Hence if you are using `routes` file then `Router.Attrs.HandlerDef` should always be available. As a shorthand instead of

```
val handlerDef: HandlerDef = request.attrs.get(Router.Attrs.HandlerDef).get
```

your can use `apply` sugar like so

```
val handlerDef: HandlerDef = request.attrs(Router.Attrs.HandlerDef)
```